# How to escape single and double quotes together in sql lite in android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, escaping, quotes

How to escape single quotes and double quotes, if string is

```
t"'e'"s""t''
```

in other words how to escape quotes in string which have single and double quotes together.

The example something like this:

```
    String whereClauseToTracks = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " = '" + artist + "' "; // t"'e'"s""t'' - instead of artist
    Cursor cursorToTracks = mResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM }, whereClauseToTracks, null, null);
```

I get sql lite exception when string contains quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `selectionArgs` and `?` in `selection` like this:

```
String selection= MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " = ?";
Cursor cursorToTracks = mResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM }, selection, new String[] {artist}, null);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it breaks with this: `String sql = "My \' bad \" sql";`

Comment: how exactly should `sql` looks without escaping ? `My ' bad " sql` ? then you should not escape single apostrophe ...

Answer (score 0):

use \' \"

```
String whereClauseToTracks = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + " = '" + "t\"\'e\'\"s\"\"t\'\'" + "' ";
```